# I want to assign the number value from a select to a variable to be used for further calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there  a way to define a variable as an integer and then within a select statement assign the calculated value to the variable, so that the variable value can then be used further in  the select statement .

```
declare avg integer;
select
  Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES,
  0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3))
```

I want to move the value from the select into avg and then use avg further on in the select.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone say, you should use `SELECT...INTO`, but don't forget to put it in `BEGIN...END` section, it can't be in declaration section (everyone omit it)

```
declare avg integer;
BEGIN
select Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3))  
INTO avg
From DUAL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can do it like this

```
declare @avg integer;
set @avg = (select
            Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES,
            0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3)))
select @avg
```

And Oracle syntax should be like this as i remember

```
declare avg integer
BEGIN
select Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES,
         0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3)) into avg
from dual
END
```

Comment: Yeah, i seen SQL tag and posted answer, after your notification i saw the other tag ... but thank you for pointing it out

Comment: declare avg integer;
Select 
Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES,
  0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3))into avg,

Comment: With DECLARE it expects a BEGIN and END - Is this correct ? where should the begin and end go as it keeps giving error message

Comment: The first example is not "SQL" - that's T-SQL (SQL - the query language - has no notion of variables)

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle you need to use SELECT INTO Clause

```
select Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3))  
INTO avg
From DUAL;
```

If this need to be done for more than one row then using cursor is advisable

```
declare
avg integer;
Begin
    For Cur in ( select Round(PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(TOTAL_CYCLES, 0, 1, TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3)) as avg From V_COMB_PROD_CRW1)
    Loop
        dbms_output.put_line("Processing ... "||Cur.avg);
        avg := Cur.avg ;
        -- process your code here using avg variable

    End Loop;

end;
/
```

Comment: Getting the following error message: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows                                             declare avg integer;
BEGIN
select Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3))  
INTO avg
From V_COMB_PROD_CRW1;
END;

Comment: Thats means Your query is returning more than one rows, hence it cannot be stored in single variables instead you need to use cursor for it. I will edit my answer to show how to do it

Comment: Thanks Narendra- That would be most helpful

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to assign values with the help of Select.

```
Declare @avg Integer
Select @avg = Round(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.PROD_HRS * 3600 / Decode(V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES,
            0, 1, V_COMB_PROD_CRW1.TOTAL_CYCLES, 20, -3)))
```

Comment: That's not valid for Oracle (and it's not valid standard SQL either)

Comment: Its not about the function used for Sql server. Check the question. Its about how to assign value to the variable for further calculation. Please be specific with question.

Comment: I didn't ask the question - but the question is clearly tagged `oracle` and your code will not work with Oracle.

Comment: The question is tagged to sql as well.

Comment: The tag `sql` means "standard (ANSI) SQL".  SQL is just a query language - not a DBMS product. If the question was for SQL Server it would have been tagged `sql-server`

Comment: Stop chit chat...sql is not proprietary of oracle...and mysql sql query can also take place if its tagged with sql..try to help each other..

Comment: And how exactly does this help someone using Oracle? (like JMS who asked the question)